# difference between public certificate and public key of any web application

Tags: ssl-certificate, single-sign-on

My team is working on the sso integration of an application.the sso team 
is asking for .cert file,but i have only the public key file which is of .pem format.
can the public key alone be used instead of a public certificate for SSO integration of any application.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/620121/what-is-the-difference-between-a-certificate-and-a-key-with-respect-to-ssl

Comment: i am not asking just the difference..please read the scenario that i have explained..just the public key alone is enough for federating ?? or a .cert file is required